# how to test bits of an integer in Assembly

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

How do I test for the least significant bit that's unset if I'm given an integer N.
My first attempt (gas syntax):

```
#define N      %ecx
#define return %eax

 /* prototype:
  * int leastSigUnsetBit(unsigned int N)
  */

.text
.global leastSigUnsetBit
leastSigUnsetBit:

movl N, 4(%esp)     

movl $-1, return
Loop:
    inc return
    bt return, N
    jc Loop
ret
```

Comment: Invert with `not`, then `bsf`?

Comment: @Michael, No! because **that** will give undefined output when the input is -1.

Comment: @Johan: Seems to me like `ZF` could be used to detect that.

Comment: @Michael, yes, see my code below.

Answer (score 3):

You can test the lsb **set** using `bsf` (bit scan forward) or even better using `tzcnt`
I hope you are aware of the fact that `bsf` will return undefined data when the operand is zero.  `tzcnt` fixes that.
If you want to test the LSB that's **unset**, you just invert the input using `not` and then test for the `LSB` set.

Note that `tzcnt` is both (nearly) reverse compatible and faster than `bsf`. `tzcnt` will be read by an old cpu as `rep bsf reg,reg`, however tzcnt modifies the flags differently from `bsf`:

```
bsf: ZF=0 -> input was 0.
tzcnt: ZF=0 -> output is 0, CF=0 -> input was zero.
```

The best solution is to use `tzcnt`, but make sure you've tested that the cpu supports `tzcnt` (or it will execute a `bsf` and your code will give incorrect results).

```
;Intel syntax
mov eax,not(-1)
tzcnt edx,eax     ;edx = 32     
mov eax,[random]
not eax           
tzcnt eax,eax
```

The other alternative is to test whether the operand is zero and adjust accordingly.
`bsf` **does** alter the flags correctly, you can use that to compensate.

From: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSF.html

> BSF 
>   .....
>   Flags Affected
>
> The ZF flag is set to 1 if all the source operand is 0;

```
not eax
mov edx,32
bsf eax,eax       
cmovz eax,edx         //force result to 32 if zero inputted.
```

*Note that as a matter of principle I don't write AT&T syntax, you'll have to reverse the operands where applicable.*

[`tzcnt` runs a lot faster than `bsf`](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) (because the cpu does not it does not have to do undefined behaviour emulation).

Comment: You have to make a stand at times, and that is a good principal to stand on.

Comment: Was not in question, but just for my fun, to extract the least significant unset bit as bit mask: `lea edx,[eax+1]` `and eax,edx` `xor eax,edx` (not sure if this is better than `tzcnt` + building up the mask from result of that, but this one is 80386 compatible (yeah, I got stuck in that era)).